# Detect circles of the following picture MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to detect the cirles on the notes. with the code following:

```
A = imread('note.png');
A = rgb2gray(A);   
 imshow(A)
    [centers, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(A,[1 15]);

    centersStrong5 = centers(1:5,:); 
    radiiStrong5 = radii(1:5);
    metricStrong5 = metric(1:5);

    viscircles(centersStrong5, radiiStrong5,'EdgeColor','b');
```

However matlab's imfindcircles seems to fail which i cant understand why.... i also changed the radius of circle which is the command [1 15] with getting more circles as adusting the parameter of to centers(1:x,:) so that it will get all the circles but still;

The result i get:

[image: Failed Circles]

Comment: that's what happens if you blindly throw unknown algorithms at a problem.
a butter knife doesn't cut stone very well...

Comment: Optical Mark Recognition (OMR) is a broad field with lots of resources available. You should probably read around the subject more before throwing `imfindcircles` at your image, for instance see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675077/ocr-for-sheet-music) on reading music. Posting two broad questions here within a couple of hours is unlikely to get you much help. If you get stuck on the specific implementation of some method, then come and ask, showing before and after, expected results etc. Forcing yourself to explain things fully will likely help you solve the problem!

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any circles in this image. This is why the algorithm cannot find them. The closest thing to a circle is the letter G.

I hope this answers your question.

Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle

I guess you're looking for the lower part of the notes.
Use a template based approach or maybe blob analysis after some preprocessing that  removes all lines.